# Python How do you compare the values of a list to a file and then save the values to a new file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, search

I'm new to python and working on my final project for my course. I'm having a hard time getting the program to search the input file for the entire given list `list1` and write the positive return results to the output file. I've tried many things like `re.search`, making a function, using different loops, and the problem is always the same. It will only search what is in `list1[0]`. I can't figure out how to make it go through the entire list. Any help would be much appreciated as I'm sure it's something simple that I'm just not familiar with or am missing completely.

**Expected Outcome** The program will search for the words in the list (exact, but not case sensitive), it will copy the line in which it was found to the new output file and then move onto the next word in the list until the list is finished.

It is currently just copying the word from the first position in the list to the file and not moving on. I'm not sure if it is copying the entire line since the line is just the word.

```
# Ask user for needed keywords or symbols
user_keywords = input("What keywords or special symbols would you like to search the provided file for?\n"
                      "Please separate each entry with a comma.\nIf you would like to just search for question marks,"
                      " please just type n.\n")
# Holding list, using comma as a way to separate the given words and symbols
list1 = list(user_keywords.split(','))
# Print list for user to see
print("You have entered the following keywords and/or special symbols: ", list1)

# Opens a new file for saving the results to.
print("Please list the path you would like the new file to save to. Example: C:\ Users \ NAME \Desktop\File name.")
outFileName = input()
outFile = open(outFileName,'w')


def filter_lines_by_keywords(lines_to_filter, key_words):
    key_words_s = set(key_words)
    return filter(lambda l: set(l.split()) & key_words_s, lines_to_filter)

# Opens the file under review.
with open(path1,'r+') as file1:
    file1lines = file1.readlines()

    res = filter_lines_by_keywords(lines_to_filter= file1lines, key_words= list1)
    outFile.write(str(list(res)))

outFile.close()
```

Please let me know if I've left anything out that is needed in the code, I think I included it all. I've checked for similar topics and couldn't find one, but if it exists please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all are you looking for exact word matches. Should someone type in "D" should it match with string "Dog" ? . Also what is the output expected. Is it the line that is having the character ?

Comment: Exact word matches, but not case sensitive. Output should be the lines from the input file copied to the output file. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify what you are doing by opening both files at the same time using context manager and also use the `any` operator to test against your keywords entered.

```
user_keywords = input("What keywords or special symbols would you like to search the provided file for?\n"
                      "Please separate each entry with a comma.\nIf you would like to just search for question marks,"
                      " please just type n.\n")

#string.split() already return a list so you dont have to turn it into a list again
list1 = [s.lower() for s in user_keywords.split(",")] #to achieve case insensitive

print("You have entered the following keywords and/or special symbols: ", list1)

print("Please list the path you would like the new file to save to. Example: C:\ Users \ NAME \Desktop\File name.")
outFileName  = input()

with open(path1, "r") as f, open(outFileName ,"w") as w:
    f = f.readlines()
    for line in f:
        if any(s in line.lower() for s in keywords): #test against all the items in keywords; return True if there is a hit
            w.write(line)
```

Comment: So for some this is only returning things in position 0 and 4. So I used a list that should've had results on positions 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, and 7. Any idea why that's happening using this code? An example would be if the list contains the words: age, bob, location, sarah, things, ?. And the file it's going through contains all the words except for sarah, and I'm only getting back the lines associated age and things.

Comment: Obviously I wouldn't know what you mean by positions 0,1,2... please provide a sample of your data and also your source file as reference.

Comment: List position 0, you like list1[0]. My source file has random words in it like bob, thing, more things, age, location, ?, 9/19/2019, temp, chat, log. My list when I wrote that response had the words I included: age, bob, location, sarah, things, ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use generators

```
# Ask user for needed keywords or symbols
user_keywords = input("What keywords or special symbols would you like to search the provided file for?\n"
                      "Please separate each entry with a comma.\nIf you would like to just search for question marks,"
                      " please just type n.\n")
# Holding list, using comma as a way to separate the given words and symbols
list1 = list(user_keywords.split(','))
# Print list for user to see
print("You have entered the following keywords and/or special symbols: ", list1)

# Opens a new file for saving the results to.
print("Please list the path you would like the new file to save to. Example: C:\ Users \ NAME \Desktop\File name.")
outFileName = input()
outFile = open(outFileName,'w')

added_lines = []


def filter_lines_by_keywords(lines_to_filter, key_words):
    global added_lines
    for line in lines_to_filter:
        input_words = line.rstrip().lower().split(' ')
        for word in key_words:
            if word.lower() in input_words and line not in added_lines:
                added_lines.append(line)
                yield line


# Opens the file under review.
with open(path1,'r+') as file1:
    file1lines = file1.readlines()

    res = filter_lines_by_keywords(lines_to_filter= file1lines, key_words= list1)
    for i in res:
        outFile.write(str(i))

outFile.close()
```

If you don't want to match punctuation, you'd have to strip that out of the line as well.